# Calculating the highest density amongst all possible lattice packings?

Tags: atoms

In the concept of sphere packing, which type of packing would have the highest packing density amongst all types of cubic lattice packings?

Comment: A small amount of research would have answered your question, e.g.: [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing#Dense_packing) and [close packing of equal spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres).

Comment: I had proved this today in school. I was fascinated by the idea of it and that is why I shared it, and yes, I did research on it. I just used one of the features Physics SE had to offer - https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Note that you did not prove that FCC is the optimum: you just calculated its density.

Comment: Yes, I did not prove that it has the maximum packing density, but I did start the answer with the statement that it had the maximum. The question merely asked which had the highest packing density and what it would be,  and not to prove that the FCC had the maximum against all lattice packings.

Comment: I can't see any signature of a homework here.

Comment: Why is this put as off-hold? I thought Physics SE had this feature of sharing your knowledge, by answering your own question, Q & A style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, in all types of cubic lattice arrangements, the face-centered cubic has the highest average packing density. Take a face centered cubic unit cell of length $a$, and each of the atoms (assuming atoms to be perfect spheres) have a radius $r$. You have a situation like this -

[image]

Let us first establish a relation between the side of the unit cell and the radius of each atom attached partially to it.

Since each lattice point represents a complete atom, such that two atoms fill a side partially. Therefore, in each face, the face diagonal must be covered by 3 atoms.(2 partially covering it, 1 completely).

Using Pythagoras,
$$
a^2 + a^2 = {(r + 2r + r)}^2
$$

$$
a = 2\sqrt{2}r\tag{1}
$$

Recall that the atomic packing factor/packing efficiency is given by 
$$
\text{APF} = \dfrac{N_{particle} V_{particle}}{V_{unit cell}}\tag{2}
$$

Where $N_{particle}$ is the number of atoms per unit cell, $V_{particle}$ is the volume of each atom and $V_{unit cell}$ is the volume of the entire unit  cell.

In total, we have $8 + 6$ spheres fixed partially throughout the unit cell. Since the atoms at the vertices contribute only $\dfrac{1}{8}$ of its total part, and the atoms on the faces contribute $\dfrac{1}{2}$ of its total part, we have an **equivalent** $\dfrac{1}{8} \times 8 + \dfrac{1}{2} \times 6 = 4$ atoms per unit cell.

Therefore, we have the following -

$$N_{particle} = 4$$

$$V_{particle} = \dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3$$

$$V_{unit cell} = a^3$$

Plugging these into $(2)$,
$$
\text{APF} = \dfrac{4 \times \dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3}{a^3}
$$
From $(1)$, we have,
$$
\text{APF} = \dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.74048
$$

Which is the required result.

Comment: FCC is not the only lattice to have this packing factor. There is another one with the exact same value of the packing factor but it does not have cubic symmetry. Do you know what is this other one?
By the way,the proof that this value is the maximum possible for identical hard spheres is not trivial. A proof was found only quite recently (2000-2005)  and the paper with the abridged proof was over 100 pages.  It relies heavily on computational power.

Comment: I was targeting cubic structures only. The other one which has the same value of the packing factor is the HCP lattice. And, no, I did not prove that this was the highest packing density amongst cubic arrangements, but I did begin it with saying that it had the highest amongst all type of cubic lattice arrangements. Yes, that proof is not trivial, as it is a proof by exhaustion, requiring computers.